# How to delete a certain row of a TreeView table - Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

Hello I want to know how can I delete a certain row of a TreeView table. For example I want to delete first row of table.

I know that we can delete a row by selecting it like:

```
selected_item = tree.selection()[0]
tree.delete(selected_item)
```

But I don't want to select. I just want to delete a certain row with a certain value before actually the whole TreeView display (yeah you would say.. "just don't insert it in the first place" but I want to know).

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first extract all the rows, then iterate through them and delete any rows matching a certain condition. Something like the following (replace the if condition with whatever your deletion criteria is)

```py
for row in tree.get_children():
    if tree.item(row) == {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}:
        tree.delete(row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. So, the rows data are always in dictionary format?

Comment: Yes they are dictionaries. You can try and iterate through them yourself in debugging mode to check the structure

Comment: Hello i want to ask you something it seems like the row data is not correct. is there any way we can know row dictionary data.

Comment: how is the row data wrong? you extract the row data by using the `tree.item(row)` command, so you can print how it looks and make your if statement based on that